# Javascript Detect All Values of Array in another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have an array `const series = [0,4,8]` and another array `const positions = [0,3,4,7,8]`

How would I detect if all of the values of `series` are included in `positions`?

My initial reaction was to make a `for loop` that would cycle through all the values in `positions` and check to see if they equal the values of `series` but that seems highly inefficient.

Comment: use `binary search` so overall complexity would be `n * logn`

Comment: Are the input arrays supposed to be sorted, or is it only a coincidence? Can there be repeats in any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `Set` object lacks set-theoretical methods, on the bright side, they are easy to implement:

```js
class RealSet extends Set {
    isSuperSet(iterable) {
        for (let x of iterable) {
            if (!this.has(x))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // @TODO: union, intersect, isSubSet, etc.
}

series = [0,4,8]
positions = [0,3,4,7,8]

console.log(new RealSet(positions).isSuperSet(series))
```

See also: [TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods) for set methods.

Comment: Set methods are a [TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods), and there are [polyfills](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods#polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

worst case complexity will be `n * log(n)`. `n` for looping all elements in `series array` and `log(n)` for binary search.

```js
const positions = [0, 3, 4, 7, 8];
const series = [0, 4, 8];

function bsearch(Arr, value) {
  var low = 0,
    high = Arr.length - 1,
    mid;
  while (low <= high) {
    mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (Arr[mid] == value) return mid;
    else if (Arr[mid] < value) low = mid + 1;
    else high = mid - 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
let i;
for (i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
  const pos = bsearch(positions, series[i]);
  if (pos === -1) break;
}

if (i === series.length) {
  console.log("All element present");
} else {
  console.log("All elmenet not present");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this would be to use Javascript builtins [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

It would go something like this,

```js
// Returns true if all elements in firstArray are also in secondArray
firstArray.every(element => secondArray.indexOf(element) !== -1)
```

The [`every` builtin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) loops through the array, running your callback on each element and returns true if your callback returned true (or truthy values) for all elements, otherwise returns false.

The [`indexOf` builtin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) searches for the argument you give it in the array with reference equality, returns the index of the argument if it is in the array, or returns -1 if it isn't.

So for every element in firstArray we check if it is in secondArray and then return true if it is by checking if indexOf returns -1 or not.

Combining these, we can solve this problem in a one-liner. For unsorted arrays, this is the best you can get. However, if you assume the array is sorted, you can get much faster using binary search. As the answer before me uses.

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays (both of them) are sorted and they don't contain repeats, you can walk through them this way:

```js
//const series = [0,4,8];
const positions = [0,3,4,7,8];

function check(series,positions){
  let pos=0;
  for(let item of series){
    while(positions[pos]<item && pos<positions.length)
      pos++;
    if(pos==positions.length || positions[pos]!==item)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log("true?",check([0,4,8],positions));
console.log("true?",check([0],positions));
console.log("false?",check([5],positions));
console.log("true?",check([8],positions));
console.log("false?",check([0,4,5],positions));
```